# How to get the Language indicator to change when switching between active applications?

Tags: language-support, input-language

Before upgrading to 12.04, the language indicator used to change every time I was sending LibreOffice to the background and making Firefox the active application/window.

This was convenient enough as I didn't have to manually change the input language each time I needed to search for a term in English in the web or in a dictionary, and then change it again to Greek in order to continue typing.

Now, this is exactly what's happening after upgrading to 12.04.

How can I manage to make the language flag change every time I switch between applications?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in the `Advanced` tab of the Ibus settings gui (type `ibus` into the dash or hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `ibus-setup` to find this gui) and unchecking `Share the same input method among all applications` if it is checked (see below).

[image: ibus settings]

I cannot reproduce your problem using Libreoffice, Firefox and a Chinese input method, but I noticed this box is not checked for me.  Maybe the upgrade process somehow enabled this setting for you (although its weird that it didn't do the same for me....).

Good luck!

Comment: I checked ibus and deselected "Share the same input method among all applications" option, but it didn't work even after login out and back in from the user's account...! Shouldn't this be an issue of gconf...?